# SASS Web essentials compiler global variable on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, twitter-bootstrap-3, compiler-errors, sass, web-essentials

I have visual studio 2013 express for web with web essentials 2013. and I'm working with SASS (bootstrap 3)

I've noticed that whenever I am editing a partial file like _table.scss I get a list of errors of undeclared variables.

This becomes a problem when i need to compile the files.

I have no issues when I'm working with sublime using a ruby compiler.

The Errors disappears when I place a @import "variables"; a partial file.

I'm new to VS2013 and I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, as long as the parent SCSS file (the one being compiled) is importing the variables file and this is imported before the other partials then this will compile fine.

**Example**

_table.scss

```
.bacon {
  color: @my-colour;
}
```

site.scss

```
@import "variables" // Contains @my-colour
@import "table";
```

If the problem you are describing is the squiggly lines when viewing your SASS partial in Visual Studio, you can add a reference to the top of the partial file to get rid of these.

**Example**

```
/// <reference path = "_variables.scss">
```

Comment: I'm having the problem with green squigglies in VS2017 with BS4 where I reference any color variables like $black or $gray-300.  I have the line `@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` and everything compiles fine.  I tried adding `/// <reference path = "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss">` as the first line in the file, but it didn't clear up the squigglies.  Any suggestions?  TIA!

Comment: Fixed.  I thought it would be the path from the folder containing the angular.json to the _variables.scss (since the Angular CLI handles the SASS compilation).  I was wrong.  It's the relative path from the styles.scss; just add "../" to the beginning and it works fine.